# Read bytes of hard drive

Tags: c++, windows, hard-drive, read-write

Using the hex editor [HxDen](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) one can read (and edit) the bytes on the hard drive or a USB key or the RAM. That is, one can read/change the first byte on the hard disk.

I understand how to [read the bytes from a file using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542519/how-to-read-a-byte-and-save-ascii-value-of-byte-in-integer-in-c), but I was wondering how one might do this for the hard disk.

To make it simple, given a positive integer n, how can I read byte number n on the hard drive using C++? (I would like to do C++, but if there is an easier way, I would like to hear about that.)

I am using [MinGW](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.mingw.org/&ei=dUa2Uu-sK8KIyAGk-ICYAg&usg=AFQjCNEvRga3K2wHNky3Nsi91j4KZaJjEA&sig2=2ShHDtDRPDAR_eCydLDrwg&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc) on Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: Maybe this will help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289453/reading-hard-disk-sectors-in-c-on-linux

Comment: @Half_Baked He's on Windows 7 (and yes, that _matters_)

Comment: @sehe:  You might say the advice was... half baked?

Comment: I edited the question after Half_Baked wrote his comment.... (sorry)

Comment: I'd start with `\\physicaldevice\` (search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=physicaldevice)

Comment: @sehe Don't think that will help ;-)

Comment: @Half_Baked I don't see why that's funny.  At least it is closer already as it leads to the arcane device naming syntax required on Windows.  If I had remembered more specifics you could have expected me to post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 9):

It is documented in the MSDN Library article for [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), section "Physical Disks and Volumes".  This code worked well to directly read the C: drive:

```
HANDLE hdisk = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\C:", 
                          GENERIC_READ, 
                          FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                          nullptr, 
                          OPEN_EXISTING, 
                          0, NULL);
if (hdisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    int err = GetLastError();
    // report error...
    return -err;
}

LARGE_INTEGER position = { 0 };
BOOL ok = SetFilePointerEx(hdisk, position, nullptr, FILE_BEGIN);
assert(ok);

BYTE buf[65536];
DWORD read;
ok = ReadFile(hdisk, buf, 65536, &read, nullptr);
assert(ok);
// etc..
```

Admin privileges are required, you must run your program elevated on Win7 or you'll get error 5 (Access denied).